# Apollo Client useQuery always return loading as true

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

I have a react component that uses apollo client and uses useQuery to get information from the API. The problem I'm facing is the loading state of useQuery is always true. I've tried Adding `fetchPolicy` to `no-cache`and  `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` to `true` but still doesn't work. I am sure the query is okay because I can get response using the graphql userinterface. Below is my code for the component

```
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import {
    Box, Grid, Alert
} from '@mui/material';
import ChapterCardSkeleton from '@components/Chapter/ChapterCard/Skeleton'

const GET_SERIE_CHAPTERS = gql`the_query_here`

function ChapterListItems(props) {
    const serieSlug = props.serieSlug

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_SERIE_CHAPTERS, {
        variables: {
            slug: serieSlug
        },
        fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    });

    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

    if (loading) return (
        <Box sx={{ pt: 1, pb: 1 }}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                {
                    numbers.map((number) => {
                        return (
                            <Grid key={number.toString()} item xs={6} sm={4} >
                                <ChapterCardSkeleton />
                            </Grid>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    )

    if (error) return (<Alert severity="error">Error! {error.message}</Alert>);

    return (
        <Box sx={{ pt: 1, pb: 1 }}>
            {JSON.stringify(data)}
        </Box>
    );
}

export default ChapterListItems
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks

By the way below are my project dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.10",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.4",
    "graphql": "^16.3.0",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-timeago": "^6.2.1"
  }``
```

`

Comment: You can try to set up code-gen with apollo, which is type safe with gql and variables

Comment: @Enfieldli im not sure how to do that in wpgraphql :(

Comment: Have you double checked the actual gql`the_query_here`  is correct? and the type of slug

Comment: yeah I have double check that part and its working. I can get response on that. Do you want me to update the question with the real query?

Answer (score 1):

I never use wp service before, but the docs has [this](https://www.wpgraphql.com/docs/interacting-with-wpgraphql/), maybe you can use fetch api to debug if the network work first, and it seems not to be an useQuery issue:

```
fetch('https://www.wpgraphql.com/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `
        {
            generalSettings {
                url
            }
        }
    `,
  }),
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
```

Comment: Hi thanks to you I was able to debug the cause of the issue. it was the environment variable that is changing, I don't know why its changing. But you are correct this is not an issue with useQuery but the environment variable which is not correct.

Comment: its not really changing but its undefined.

Comment: Yep. Glad it help!